# Execute the second request in 2 seconds as the first request

Tags: angular

I have two requests.
And I need `this.auth.login` to be executed in 2 seconds after `this._auth.create` is executed.

This is not happening to me.
What have I done wrong?

```
auth() {
  this._auth.create(this.form.value).subscribe(
    () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this._auth.login(this.form.value).subscribe(
          () => {
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          },
          error => {
            this._toast.error(error.error.message);
          }
        );
      }, 2000)
      },
    error => {
      this._toast.error(error.error.message);
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid nested subscriptions as much as possible. Instead you could use RxJS [operators](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators) to mix and match multiple (co-dependent) observables.

Try the following

```js
auth() {
  this._auth.create(this.form.value).pipe(
    delay(2000),
    switchMap(_ => this._auth.login(this.form.value))
  ).subscribe(
    _ => this.router.navigate(['/home']),
    error => this._toast.error(error.error.message)
  );
}
```

I've used [`delay`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/delay) operator to delay the notification from first request for 2 seconds and switch it to the second request using [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator.

But inducing a fixed delay in a login procedure isn't good design. If you have some side-effects that needs to be fulfilled during this delay, another way would be to involve these side-effects in the routing procedure and make the second call directly wait on the first call instead of a hard delay.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be more readable if you'd use what RxJS offers:

```js
concat(
  this._auth.create(this.form.value).pipe(
    tap({ error: () => this._toast.error(error.error.message) }),

    // make sure it goes to the next observable provided to `concat()`
    catchError(() => EMPTY)
  ),
  timer(2000).pipe(
    switchMap(
      () => this._auth.login(this.form.value).pipe(
        tap({
          next: () => this.router.navigate(['/home']);,
          error: () => this._toast.error(error.error.message);,
        }),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      )
    ),
  ),
);
```